# Ajax backed List/Menu

Tags: javascript, dojo, spring-js

I am developing a web application using Spring JS and Dojo Toolkit.

In this application I want a Menu that lists the different organzational units in my application. The users will be able to add/remove these units and I want the menu to immediately reflect those changes.

Example:
My user adds an new organizational unit "Strategic Consulting". So he/she expects this new unit to show in the menu to his left among the other units like "Marketing" "Sales" etc.

So basically I need a Menu that is backed by some collection of business units on the serverside.

How do I do this using the Dojo Toolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do that by yourself. When a new organization unit is added, you can add a new `dijit.MenuItem` to the `dijit.Menu`.